# Writing a new column in a csv file through Command line

Tags: optparse

I want to create a python script that will write a new column in a csv file along with the data through command line, using optparse.

For e.g. if following is the input file(script_name.py) :-

```
User_ID,Date,Num_1,Num_2,Com_ID
101,2015-04-13,12,21,1011
102,2014-4-3,1,7,1002
```

then **python script_name.py Num_3 1101 1102**. will create a new column with data.
Can anybody please direct me somewhere where I can learn how to achieve this ??I already read about OptParse but got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

the args variable will contain an array of all arguments
than using simple loops you can run over the file and add the contents of the args variable

Comment: without writing the code? than why you want python?